# Disabling onclick within if statement

Tags: onclick

I have a quick question about disabling an onclick after the action has been processed. This is for a form which can be viewed back at a later time. The problem is that when you are in the view I do not want the onclick function to be run actually I want the radio button to stay selected from what was submitted.

```
<input type="radio" name="#str#"  id="#str#" value="yes"  onclick="valuechanged(this)"
<cfif  len(#audit#) gt 0 and  getsafetytype.weight eq colvalue>     
checked="yes"                                   
</cfif>
```

So the view command runs the if statement have having a value. I can not figure out how to make the onclik disable during the if statement without disabling it when a new form is being created. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: have you tried doing this:  onclick="return false;"

Comment: I don't understand the question?  Under what conditions do you want `onclick` to be disabled?  and where is this `"if statement"` you speak of?

Comment: The if statement is cfif sorry should have stated this is a mixture of coldfusion and it is calling for a javascript funcition called "valuechange". I want the onclick to be disabled after the form has been submitted so it can not be changed again if you go back to it.

Comment: Disregard this I am actually just going to work around this by implementing a try block in the javascript to do what I need thanks for everyones help